# Show which room a bookmarked chat conversation is in, without clicking through?

Tags: feature-request, chat, chat-bookmarks

Every chat room has a link for conversations bookmarked in that room.  But users also have a bookmarks list, and that list includes all of that user's bookmarked conversations across the network.  This list shows title, dates, duration, and who bookmarked it -- but not the room in which the conversation happened.  Further, the URL isn't helpful in that regard unless you make a habit of memorizing room numbers.

Because of this I'm sometimes tempted to include the room name (or a shorthand) when I bookmark a conversation, so I can easily identify it in my list, but that would look pretty silly in the *room's* list.

Could we make this information available somehow?  I can think of two ways to convey useful information without fundamentally altering the layout of the bookmarks list:

1. Show the site's icon in the bookmark on the same line as the title.  This doesn't fully address the question if a site has more than one room, but at least it's a hint.
2. When viewing a user's bookmarks, instead of showing "bookmarked by (name)", which is redundant, show something like "boomarked in (room name)".  This would require different display code for the two types of bookmark lists, so may not be practical or desirable.  (I think we do still want to see who bookmarked conversations in the *room's* list.)

Or, adopting a suggestion balpha made in comments, just include both pieces of information in all places where the conversation is listed (user and room):

[image: mockup]

Comment: That's a pretty good idea. Should probably just show "by X" and "in Y" all the time, instead of making it different depending on where you are.

Comment: @balpha, oh good idea -- that works too.